# C11 mixing atomic and non-atomic access to variable

Tags: c, atomic, c11

Sometimes you may want to access a variable both atomically and non-atomically. Which is why I find convinient that on gcc you can write something like :

```
int var = 0;
var++;
atomic_fetch_add(&var, 1);
```

However this does not compile with clang 4.0.1 :

```
error: address argument to atomic operation must be a pointer to _Atomic type ('int *' invalid)
atomic_fetch_add(&var, 1);
```

The best solution I could find is a cast :

```
int var = 0;
(*(int*)&var)++;
atomic_fetch_add(&var, 1);
```

Is there a simpler and portable way to achieve this ?

Comment: "this does not compile with clang" --- an error message would be helpful.

Comment: Btw, what is the original purpose of doing that? The first value change is not guaranteed to be seen by other thread, so the `var++;` value may be effectively not applied at all.

Comment: How *could* this work? `_Atomic int` and `int` are different types, so pointers to them will not convert automatically. If you cast manually, you get undefined behavior for access to an object through an lvalue expression not of the effective type of the object (and not of a character type).

Comment: From C++ but related: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4013.html . I hope C adapts something like this. Like right now I'm finding myself wanting to use a bit iterator function on a bit array overlayed over a dynamic number of size_t-typed cells and I want to do it from a differently thread but only for a hint. So what the C standard rules now want me to rewrite the functions in terms of relaxed atomics or else UB? That spec is retarded. And it seems Linus Torvalds agrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abstract machine defined by the C Standard has a rather different view of storage than most real machines.  In particular, rather than thinking of memory accesses as actions which can be performed in a variety of different way depending upon required circumstances, it instead views each object has supporting one kind of read and at most one kind of write (`const`-qualified objects don't support any kind of write); the kind of read and write required to access an object depend upon its type.

Such an approach may be useful for some kinds of hardware platforms, or for some optimization strategies, but is grossly unsuitable for many kinds of programs running on real-world platforms.  Unfortunately, the Standard doesn't recognize any practical way by which programmers can indicate that certain objects should be treated as "ordinary" storage most of the time, but recognize that they require more precise memory semantics at certain specific times during program execution.

Answer (score 3):

There are two interfaces in C11 that allow you to act on an atomic object which are less restrictive.

First, you can always overwrite an atomic object, when you know that you are the only one accessing it, usually during an initialization phase, use `atomic_init` for that.

Second, if you need less guarantees for an access during the execution even with several threads, you can use a less restrictive access mode. Namely you could e.g do `atomic_fetch_and_add_explicit(&var, 1, memory_order_relaxed)`. This still guarantees that your access is *indivisible* (one of the properties that you want from an atomic) but it doesn't guarantee when another thread sees the updated value.

But generally speaking, if atomic accesses are performance critical, you are doing something wrong. So before you try semantically difficult dealings with atomics, benchmark your code and see if this really is a bottleneck. If so, think first of a way to change your algorithm, e.g by doing more computations in local variables that are not subject to races. Only if all of that fails to give you the performance you want, have a look into the different memory semantics that C11 offers.